# mod_filter to change content on a site

Tags: apache2, proxypass, mod-filter

What I am trying to accomplish is to remove specific content on the user end from a site that is being proxyed. I have checked to make sure the correct modules are loaded and running. My virtual host looks like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
ServerName proxyed-domain.com
ServerAlias www.proxyed-domain.com

ProxyPass / http://www.example.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com/

# filter to remove find a dealer
FilterDeclare MYFILTER
FilterProvider MYFILTER SUBSTITUTE resp=Content-Type $text/
FilterChain +MYFILTER
Substitute "s|<div class=\"wheretobuySearch\">([\s\S]*?)(/div>)|<div class=\"wheretobuySearch\"></div>|i"
```

Unfortunately it does not remove the content on the proxy site. Am I using mod_filter incorrectly or is there something else wrong?

Comment: Could the issue be with not using the gzip and the deflate module not being used?